# pulling 5 field values from a related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have reviewrequests that has many sitereviews. I can get at the count of the number of site reviews a given reviewrequest has in a view with: <%=h request.sitereviews.count.to_s %>

With each sitereview there's a text field - suggestions. Is there a way to get at say the last 5 sitereview.suggestions values as a single value? Something like: <%=h request.sitereviews.suggestions.last.5.to_s %>

Comment: Bob, would you expect the whole list of suggestions loaded by the time you want to get the last 5? Or you want it to generate the query for the last 5?

Comment: Pablo - SO weirdness - just got 11/30 notice of your 11/2 comment... got it done, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to request.rb

```
def latest_suggestions
  suggestions = []
  sitereviews.find(:all, :order => 'created_at desc', :limit => 5).each do |sr|
    suggestions << sr.suggestions
  end
  suggestions.join(',')
end
```

I'm guessing you mean that each site review has suggestions and you want to get the suggestions of the last 5 site reviews.

This is all pretty weird honestly, not sure why you would want this.